# What I have missed when I linked the tor container to microblog?

Tags: docker, tor

So from begin I was trying to link the microblog from [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.1) by using next commands:

```
sudo docker build -t microblog:latest .

sudo docker run --name mysql -d -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=microblog -e MYSQL_USER=microblog \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=onion~12 \
    mysql/mysql-server:5.7

sudo docker run --name elasticsearch -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
    -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
    docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.6.2

sudo docker run --name microblog -d -p 8000:5000 -e SECRET_KEY=my-secret-key \
    -e MAIL_SERVER=smtp.googlemail.com -e MAIL_PORT=587 -e MAIL_USE_TLS=true \
    -e MAIL_USERNAME=admin_onion123@gmail.com -e MAIL_PASSWORD=123456780 \
    --link mysql:dbserver \
    -e DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://microblog:onion~12@dbserver/microblog \
    --link elasticsearch:elasticsearch \
    -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 \
    microblog:latest
```

Up here everything is perfect!

Now I was getting the docker container with Tor Hidden-Service from [here](https://libraries.io/github/cmehay/docker-tor-hidden-service) by using next command:

```
sudo docker run -itd --link microblog goldy/tor-hidden-service
```

The ideea is when I am using the command :

```
sudo docker logs {container of tor}
```

is showing me the myrandomoninonaddress.onoin:5000.

**What I did wrong or what I have missed and why is listening port 5000 instead of 8000?**

Comment: Because you're mapping 8000 on the host to 5000 in the container? The logs show you what port the container is listening on.

Comment: the idea is how to make the tor container to listen the port 8000 which is port associated with my localhost:8000, and the microblog content to be showed on myrandomoninonaddress.onoin. How to fix this?

Comment: I think perhaps you have misunderstood how docker port mapping wqorks. `-p 8000:5000` means *"map localhost:8000 to container:5000"*. The container, according to your logs, is listening on port 5000, which is mapped to `localhost:8000`. Can you `telnet locahost:8000`?

Comment: For "telnet locahost:8000" the output is: "telnet: could not resolve locahost:8000/telnet: Name or service not known" but the server is running well ...